# Angular authorization depending on url parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, routes

I am building an angular application, I need to build a login module and I found this article: [angular-auth](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.4rzzda4ph)

It seems ok, but I can't figure out how to authorize users depending on url parameters. For exmaple I have this route:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/client_details/:clientId', {
     templateUrl: 'client_details/client_details.html',
     controller: 'clientDetailsCtrl'
 });
```

I need to check that you can see the client details only if the client belongs to your list of clients. Otherwise I can just try random ids to see random clients page.

How can I do that?

Comment: Another good article on Authentication with angular http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: are you using a web service to get the clients data?

Comment: With client I mean customer not like client-server entity!
Yes I use api to get data from the server!

Comment: Then you validate the user against their request, this way you don't have to pass in a clientId because you know who is requesting it.